# Приложение - раздельное или с тире написание?

Tags: приложение

Какое значение несут за собой написания раздельное и с тире - с приложениями? Или по текущим правилам дефис можно ставить там, где раньше было раздельное написание?

Например, сочетание: **старик отец**. Возможны ли для него следующие написания и какие значения будут нести различные написания?

*Старик-отец*, *отец-старик*, *отец старик, старик отец*; *человек-инвалид, инвалид-человек, человек инвалид, инвалид человек*.

Comment: Очень интересный вопрос, и как раз по моей недавней  теме. Все эти написания в ПАС сведены на дефис (это как бы более логично, последовательно и соответствует современной практике письма).http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=281119   Хорошо бы услышать ответ от моих критиков и противников любого "новаторства".